# How to make websocket server in ASP.NET Core RC2?

Tags: c#, websocket, asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2

I use "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Server": "0.1.0-rc2-final" to make a websocket server, but not work.
(In rc1, it is 1.0.0-rc1-final, and it work fine...)

Here is my code:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseWebSockets();

        app.Use(async (http, next) =>
        {

            if (http.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                IHandler handler = WebsocketManager.getHandler(http.Request.Path);
                if (handler == null)
                {
                    await next();
                }
                else
                {
                    var webSocket = await http.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                    if (webSocket != null && webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                    {
                        // TODO: Handle the socket here.
                        WebsocketManager.Handle(webSocket, handler);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Nothing to do here, pass downstream.  
                await next();
            }
        });


        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

WebsocketManager is my own manager class.
And Here is how I handle websocket session:

```
    public async Task Listen()
    {
        OnOpen();
        while (_webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            var error = String.Empty;

            try
            {
                var buffer = new ArraySegment<Byte>(new Byte[4096]);
                var received = await _webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);

                switch (received.MessageType)
                {
                    case WebSocketMessageType.Close:
                        OnClose(received.CloseStatus, received.CloseStatusDescription);
                        break;
                    case WebSocketMessageType.Text:
                        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, buffer.Count).Trim('\0');
                        OnMessage(data);
                        break;
                    case WebSocketMessageType.Binary:
                        OnMessage(buffer.Array);
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

And then, "_webSocket.ReceiveAsync" thrown exception "The request was aborted."

I am sure client not close the session.

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to use SignalR functionality in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @JanshairKhan No, I just want to make a simple websocket listener as game server transport layer.

Comment: Are you developing and testing on Windows Server 2008 R2 or newer? As far as I know websockets are unsupported on Client OS (at least up to (including) Windows 7. Not sure about Win8/10) and requires Windows Server 2008 R2 or newer. If you run it on an unsupported OS you need to fallback to long polling or similar techniques. SignalR does that, because WebSockets aren't supported everywhere

Comment: Could you include all the relevant code (a [mcve]), so that we can replicate the issue?

Comment: fyi - it seems a stream is closed when the initial request is disposed of closing the socket. Same code was fine in RC1 - also why the bump down from 1.0.0-rc1 to 0.1.0-rc2 are we using the wrong package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `await` this line:

`WebsocketManager.Handle(webSocket, handler);`

Otherwise the request ends and the resources get disposed.

Comment: Can anyone post the fixed full code example (I have trouble implementing it in ASP.NET core)