# Any WebSocket server framework on ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, websocket, asp.net-core

Is there any high-level framework for WebSocket server in ASP.Net Core apps?

I saw the basic websocket support via Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Server nuget described on the [net](http://dotnetthoughts.net/using-websockets-in-aspnet-core/) and [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484589/how-to-make-websocket-server-in-asp-net-core-rc2). 
Is there something more high-level? SignalR would be a great example, but it's planned for 2017. Is there something available right now?

Comment: You can use the nuget package CI feed to reference alpha package of signalr and websoket, take a look on signalr GitHub repo

Comment: Not yet, coming soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [SignalW](https://github.com/Spreads/SignalW)

Efficient, has Hub and groups just like SignalIR does, and most importantly it does not force you to use a particular message format or JSON. You can adapt any protocol you like, and I use it for [JSON-RPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification)

### [Websocket-Manager](https://github.com/radu-matei/websocket-manager)

A decent implementation. It's very well documented and there is a [blogpost explaining how to re-create it yourself](https://radu-matei.com/blog/aspnet-core-websockets-middleware/). The disadvantage is that it forces you to use JSON and a spesific message format, which is not ideal if you have other clients that aren't .Net

### [Websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp)

This a server that does not rely on ASP.NET Core, it is just a websocket server and that's it - no REST, serving files, etc. This can be important if you are looking to add websocket connectivity to an application that has nothing to do with being a webserver, like a game.  [Starcraft uses websockets and protobuff](https://github.com/Blizzard/s2client-proto/blob/master/docs/protocol.md) for bot and AI development. This does work with unity.
There is [currently a discussion](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp/issues/267) about .Net Core compatiability, but I believe it's not quite done yet.